# High performance JSON text parsing and storing in SQLite

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, unsafe

I'm working on some refactoring of my Android (kotlin/java) app to greatly improve the performance of an initial data synchronization that is done with our back-end systems and stored in a local SQLite db. The app is used on all kind of Android devices this sync can take up hours on the older Android devices.

The back-end system uses an JSON (UTF-8) API with around 10.000 items per batch with a lot of strings.

To achieve the highest performance possible I think I have to find a way to use / parse Strings more efficient. With just a normal JSON parser and using the Android SQLiteStatement classes I can only do this:

1. Parse the received JSON response (in-mem byte[]) into objects with there Strings.
2. These Strings are backed by new char[] and the bytes are first copied & converted to UTF-16 to the char[]. Effectively doubling the memory needed for a String.
3. The SQLite db uses UTF-8 encoding. So binding a string to its statement also involves some conversion steps.

I already implemented some idea's but still I have some problems;

1. Instead of parsing (index-overlay-parsing) to String objects I can parse these Strings to an object which has an reference to the original byte[] buffer, offset & length. The SQLiteStatement class allows to bind a byte[] as BLOB. Effectively inserting UTF-8 bytes directly in SQLite.
   This approach is already much faster but still there is some memory copying involved. A neater approach will be that the SQLiteStatement allows to bind the original byte[] buffer with an offset and length. But this class is final...
2. Another idea was to subclass String and let this class be backed by the original byte[] buffer, offset & length. But also the String class is final...
3. Implementing some CharSequence sounds a neat approach but the SQLiteStatement does not have some method the bind that type...
4. Binary serdes does not greatly improve performance because of all the strings.

So I was wondering if you guys have some ideas how the reduce the object allocation and memory copying?

1. Can the Unsafe package do any help here? (proxy String?)
2. Another option is to copy the android.sqlite package and create my own SQLiteStatement with support for byte[]/offset/length or CharSequence.
3. Any other ideas?

Comment: I bookmarked your question earlier this year since I had some interest in it and I had a similar performance request (loading CSV data from a remote source and replicating the data to the local database). Regarding the `Unsafe` -- if it'd even work, I'd not stay with it just because it may change or even not work at other environments. Regarding the `CharSequence`: it sounds like an idea, but I'm not yet sure if it's possible. Have you achieved some performance improvements maybe?

Comment: Yes I implemented multiple ideas to speed up our process but mostly not one of the ideas mentioned.

Comment: 1. I used the DSL-JSON parser to achieve the highest parsing speed for my data(https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json).
2. I created a binary serializer to store all the list of child objects in a single column. Downside is that you cannot query anymore for them, but we didnt need that. 
3. I created a Statement Builder which uses batched inserts + caches its statements. (INSERT INTO A VALUES ((?,?),(?,?)... 
4. I create the indices at the end and remove duplicates by using ROWID.

Comment: 5. If possible I used a PK from the data instead of an auto-inc id.
6. I used coroutines to make max use of the CPU's while distributing the work load. (parsing JSON, preparing statements, Inserting into database).

All these changes made it 5x faster, the DB file 3x smaller and less memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. 3) I used a similar approach to yours by implementing a cached query builder, but I don't really recall what I actually cached (I believe, it must be query statement strings, nothing else). 4) Fortunately, the data model consumed by that app was clearly defined and had no duplicates. 5) Also it provided natural keys so I didn't even have to deal with surrogate keys like auto-increments. Additionally, Perhaps I also experimented with the `ignore_check_constraints` flag, but can't really recall it now.

Comment: I also had an idea of implementing a custom CSV parser utilizing a common `CharSequence` pool to save on duplicates while reading on fly assuming there must be duplicates, but it probably won't work with `SQLiteStatement` because it does not provide any `CharSequence`-friendly API. Anyway, while tweaking the SQLite-related stuff, I sped up the performance to about 35%: it still took about a minute to import the data on my device. Sad enough, there is probably no way to import CSV data other than I did. (I believe the SQLite shell builds the CSV import on top of what SQLite has...)

Comment: Maybe you could look at C++?

Comment: Well, maybe... I don't do C/C++ for more than a decade and half so I even wouldn't take a look at it now. It would be nice if there could be a direct way to export/import CSV data directly using dedicated API (not like the look-alike shell built-in) without those massive intermediate layers that may be implemented in very inefficient ways. Actually, I thought (cached/pooled) `CharSequence` would allow lowering some costs if it were implemented for the SQLite statements, but I merely gave up on that. Thanks for sharing your experience!